# How to pick random element from 2d String array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, random

Hi Im a newbie at java programming and i have a problem with getting an element from my 2d string array plss help me

Here is my array

```
String[][] cardDeck = { 
            { "AceH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "10H", "JackH", "QueenH", "KingH" }, 
            { "AceD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JackD", "QueenD", "KingD" },
            { "AceS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JackS", "QueenS", "KingS" },
            { "AceC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JackC", "QueenC", "KingC" }};
```

Comment: You're only picking a total of one card? Else what are you going to do if you pick the same card twice?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
String[][] cardDeck = { 
    { "AceH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "10H", "JackH", "QueenH", "KingH" }, 
    { "AceD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JackD", "QueenD", "KingD" },
    { "AceS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JackS", "QueenS", "KingS" },
    { "AceC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JackC", "QueenC", "KingC" }};
int random_y = (int)(Math.random() * cardDeck.length);
int random_x = (int)(Math.random() * cardDeck[random_y].length);
System.out.println(cardDeck[random_y][random_x]);
```

`Math.random()` returns a random DECIMAL between 0 and 1, so if we multiply it by some number `a`, we get a random decimal between 0 and `a` (non-inclusive). Converting it to int, we then get a random integer between 0 and `a`. And that's exactly what we need to get a random index!

But in this case, we'll need 2 random integers, since this is a 2D array. You can call them `random_x` and `random_y`, since they'll correspond to the random column and random row **respectively**. So we can access the random element using `cardDeck[random_y][random_x]`.

---

If you're still confused as to why we multiply it by the length of the array, consider this: to get a random row, we need to access `cardDeck[i]`, where `i` is an integer between `0` and `cardDeck.length`. In this particular *row* of the matrix, we want a random element. So we access it using `cardDeck[i][j]`, where `j` is an integer between 0 and `cardDeck[i].length`.

Comment: how about if I only need 1 random element?

Comment: This **is** only for getting 1 random element. It's just that you'll need 2 random indexes to get that random element, since this is a 2D matrix. If this were a 3D matrix, you'd need 3 random indexes, and so on.

Comment: @user16320675 That's a good point, I'll edit that into my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
String[][] cardDeck = {
        { "AceH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "10H", "JackH", "QueenH", "KingH" },
        { "AceD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JackD", "QueenD", "KingD" },
        { "AceS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JackS", "QueenS", "KingS" },
        { "AceC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JackC", "QueenC", "KingC" }};
    Random random = new Random();
    int dim1Pos = random.nextInt(cardDeck.length); // pick random position for 1st dimension (row)
    int dim2Pos = random.nextInt(cardDeck[dim1Pos].length); // pick random position for 2nd dimension (column) for previously selected row
    String randomString = cardDeck[dim1Pos][dim2Pos];
    System.out.println(randomString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `Math.random()` method, you could just use the `Random` class.

```
String[][] cardDeck = { 
    { "AceH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "10H", "JackH", "QueenH", "KingH" }, 
    { "AceD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JackD", "QueenD", "KingD" },
    { "AceS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JackS", "QueenS", "KingS" },
    { "AceC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JackC", "QueenC", "KingC" }};
Random random = new Random();
int randomX = random.nextInt(cardDeck.length);
int randomY = random.nextInt(cardDeck[0].length);
System.out.println(cardDeck[randomX][randomY]);
```

`Random` is a class which can generate random numbers, in fact, the `Math.random()` method uses the `Random` class itself. `random.nextInt(cardDeck.length);` generates a random integer between 0(inclusive) and the number of rows(exclusive), which is a valid index.
Similiarly, `random.nextInt(cardDeck[0].length);` will return a random integer between 0(inclusive) and the number of columns(exclusive), which too is the valid index.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Streams` to collect all elements to a list, and then shuffle the list:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(cardDeck).      //stream to String[]
                    flatMap(x->Arrays.stream(x)). //stream to String
                    collect(Collectors.toList()); //collect to a List 

Collections.shuffle(list);    //shuffle collection
String randomElement = list.get(0); //get an arbitrary element
```

You could also use `Streams.skip(n)` :

```
Optional<String> randomElement =  Arrays.stream(cardDeck).  //stream to String[]
                                 flatMap(x->Arrays.stream(x)). //stream to String
                                 skip(new Random().nextInt(cardDeck.length*cardDeck[0].length ))//remove random number of elements 
                                .findFirst();
```

Comment: You can also reduce your map taking random value form a pair.

Comment: @AlexeyR. please post an answer and show how

Comment: Cannot do that from my cell phone.. Basically there would be `flatMap(x->Arrays.stream(x)).reduce((s, s2) -> random.nextBoolean() ? s : s2).get()` where you initialize `random` before..

Comment: I see what you mean. It needs to be improved because as is 50%of the times it will return last element of the array.